# Facing issue with Case sensitive search in django-tastypie-mysql

Tags: mysql, django, tastypie

I am facing problem on Case insensitive search. I am using the following environment:-

```
Database: MySQL
Collation/Character Encoding: utf8bin
Framework: Django-Tastypie
```

This **collation/Character encoding** does not support the case insensitive search. So If I write

```
SELECT .... WHERE company_name LIKE '%StackOverflow%';
```

then it wont give output for **'STACKOVERFLOW'** or other combinations.

When I use Django-Tastypie filtering :-

```
company_name__icontains = 'StackOverflow'
```

And It internally fires same SQL query, hence it doesn't give the correct answer.

If I use simple MySQL query then I might use:

```
SELECT .... WHERE UPPER(company_name) like upper('%StackOverflow%');
```

But not able to write filter for above solution in the Django-Tastypie.

I found one alternative way to solve the issue using Regex:-

```
company_name__iregex = '(S|s)(T|t)(A|a)(C|c)(K|k)(O|o)(V|v)(E|e)(R|r)(F|f)(L|l)(O|o)(W|w)'
```

However, it is very slow method.

Can someone give the solution, so that I can build a filter in Tastypie for Case Insensitive Search.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had changed the character_encoding in the database level. Which support case insensitive search.

I ran following command:-

```
alter table {{table_name}} convert to character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;
```